# rails 3 and jQuery Dialog form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery

im google it, but still can't find info or tutorial.
I have a link with item, im wanna jquery dialog form onclick with item/edit this item and submit. How can im implement this? All tutorials take form from html, im wanna take it from the view and fields need to be filled with existing values.

Comment: im wanna render form from another action!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alot of this code below is from http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

i hope my added comments in the code explain what each part is doing a little better

```
    <script>

        //taken from jQueryUI dialog 'form' demo.http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form
        $(document).ready(function(event){

        var name = $( "#name" ),
                    email = $( "#email" ),
                    password = $( "#password" ),
                    allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
                    tips = $( ".validateTips" );
//taken from jQueryUI dialog 'form' demo.http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form
// validation function message helper
                function updateTips( t ) {
            tips
                .text( t )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
            setTimeout(function() {
                tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
            }, 500 );
        }
//taken from jQueryUI dialog 'form' demo.http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form
// validation function 
        function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
            if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
                o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                    min + " and " + max + "." );
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
          $("#dialog").dialog({
          height: 300,
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true,
                            open : function(event, ui){
                            // not needed b/c of ajax load
    },
                    buttons: {
                        "Save": function() {
                            var bValid = true;
                                            // clear previous validation errors.
                            // perform errror checking on dialog form values            
                            if ( bValid ) {
                                $.post("url/to/save/data", $("#dialog form").serializeArray(), function(data, text, xhr){
    // check for errors saving edits in the 'data' variable
    var hadErrors = true;
    if( data.someWayToCheckForErrors == hadErrors){
       // append an error message to the dialog without closing it, or, append an error message to the main page.
      //$("#dialog").append("<div class='ui-state-error'>you had an error saving</div>");
    }else{
     $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
    }); 
                            }
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    },
                    close: function() {

                    });



      $(".editLink").click(function(event){
               var theDialog = $("#dialog");
//shorthand ajax call to query server for the Dialog Content in another action.
               theDialog.load("someUrlToGetDataFromYourAction",
               {optional json of url parameters for Action}, 
               function(data, text, jqXhr){
// success 
theDialog.dialog("open");});

          });
        });
        </script>
```

html to make the above work, again from the demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

```
<div id="yourContent">
<table><!---whatever is in here.  also, this does not need to be a table.--->
<td><a href="#" class="editLink">edit</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
        <div id="dialog" title="Create new user">
   <!--- content provided by ajax $.load() call in $('.editLink').click() event.--->
        </div>
```

Comment: use rgould's answer, you can look at my answer if you want to see all the crazy validation stuff you can do within the dialog itself.  Also, there are two options to load the dialog's form with data.

Comment: if i have link on form. how to display this form as modal window? im dont wanna to paste html, im already have it, but it's placed in another action

Comment: i got rid of the extra html.  The html for the edit link is very simple, but the real 'go get the dialog form' work is done by the .load(); function.  is that what you are trying to do?  the rest of the work to validate the dialog form and save it is the same theoretically.

Answer (score 15):

Forms in the dialog behave just like regular forms - there is nothing special about them.

If you have a form that you use to already edit the item, wrap that in a `<div>` and give it an id. 
E.g.:

```
<div id="your_dialog">
  <% form_for ... %>
     ... rest of form goes here
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And then somewhere you'll want to set up the dialog using javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $your_dialog = $('#your_dialog').dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false, 
    title: 'Edit',
    modal: true,
    draggable: false
  });
});
</script>
```

And then hook up the dialog to some link (probably in your `public/application.js`):

```
$('#open-dialog').click(function(){
    $your_dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

And somewhere in your view you will have an element that acts the open dialog button:

```
<span id="open-dialog">Click me to open the dialog</span>
```

If you want to the dialog to be an AJAX submit, make sure to use `:remote => true` in the form parameters.

That should do it. Make sure your form works before you try and put it in a dialog (ie. get the first div/form done before trying to hook up the javascript dialog)

Comment: @rgould +1 your answer is much simpler.

Comment: im wanna render my form from the another action/view. let's say im currently in items/index and wanna render as dialog view items/edit. How can i do this, i ahvent another choice, only copy/paste code from edit view to the index view?

Comment: Take the edit view and refactor out the `form` part as a partial. Your edit view will then look something like this: `render :partial => 'form'`

Comment: Then in the index you could call `render :partial => 'form'` for each "edit" button. This is inefficient, but would work for something quick and dirty. I'd recommend asking another question (and be specific) for a more elegant solution.

Comment: i have table with 21 element, am i need to render form for all elements in td?

Comment: That would do it, but as I said, there is probably a better way to do it (i'm not that familiar with js and rails yet, so i'm not yet aware of it)

Comment: @Myth17: that usually goes in your views.